# C# NPOI exception "Extern sheet is part of LinkTable" while creating object HSSFWorkbook from FileStream

Tags: c#, excel, exception, xls, npoi

Code below throw exception "Extern sheet is part of LinkTable". Using NPOI 2.3.0 .

```
HSSFWorkbook xlsFile;

using (var fileRead = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{ 
    try
    {
        xlsFile = new HSSFWorkbook(fileRead);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

How i can open this file using NPOI? Because of Microsoft Office could open this file easily and offer to resave it. And after resaving by MS Office - NPOI opens this file (no errors with creating HSSFWorkbook object).

But i need work only with NPOI (open file, repair file if needed, do some work and save). Tried work by POIFS, instead of creating HSSFWorkbook object - this is not working, couse of POIFS already contains errors and can not access it.

[File with exception](https://dl.velesstroy.com/public/filewithexception--ru)